# iOS MapBox fit camera to multiple coordinates [latitude and longitude] or annotations

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox-ios

in MapBox documentation for android there is [`LatLngBounds`](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/fit-camera-in-bounding-box/?q=bounding&size=n_10_n), but for iOS there are nothing, is there any way todo it for iOS

Answer (score 3):

As of Mapbox v10.4.3, this solution works for me, basically you need 4 coordinates that will serve as the rect bounds for the camera.

https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/migrate-to-v10/#fit-the-camera-to-a-given-shape

Sample Snippet

```
class Coordinate {
  var longitude: Double = 0
  var latitude: Double = 0

  init(longitude: Double, latitude: Double) {
    self.longitude = longitude
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.datasetId = datasetId
  }

  func coordinates() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
  }
}

func setCoordinateBounds(bounds: [Coordinate]) -> CoordinateBounds {
    var flyTo = MKMapRect.null
      for bound in bounds {
        let point: MKMapPoint = MKMapPoint(bound.coordinates())
        let pointRect = MKMapRect(x: point.x, y: point.y, width: 0, height: 0)
        flyTo = flyTo.isNull ? pointRect : flyTo.union(pointRect)
      }
    let coordNE = MKMapPoint(x: flyTo.origin.x, y: flyTo.maxY).coordinate
    let coordSW = MKMapPoint(x: flyTo.maxX, y: flyTo.origin.y).coordinate
    return CoordinateBounds(southwest: coordSW, northeast: coordNE)
  }

// Implementation
let coordinates = [
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24, -89),
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24, -88),
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(26, -88),
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(26, -89),
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24, -89)
]
let coordinateBounds = setCoordinateBounds(bounds: coordinates)
let cameraOptions = self.mapView.mapboxMap.camera(for: coordinateBounds, padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20), bearing: self.mapView.cameraState.bearing, pitch: 0)
      self.mapView.camera.fly(to: cameraOptions, duration: 0.3, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation it appears that you just need to construct your MGLCoordinateBounds from the list of geo positions similar to the workflow of Apple Maps and then call https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/6.3.0/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapView(im)setVisibleCoordinateBounds:animated: on your map box view.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning that i'm using the latest version of MapBox (10.0.0-rc.4). the reason is Apple M1 chip. Which the current Public MapBox (v6.3.0) not support Apple M1 chip. I have [MacBook mini]. I searched for the same thing bot nothing... there isn't camera animation to CordinateBouns there are only 
 https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/10.0.0-rc.4/Classes/MapboxMap.html#/Camera%20Fitting